# Spatial Join unique values for closest target feature

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-join, proximity

I have a polygon shapefile of land plots with their corresponding cadaster number and a point shapefile with a water meters for each lot.

What I'm trying to do is to join the cadaster number from the polygon shapefile to its corresponding water meter. For this I'm using a spatial join with the point file (water meters) as my target feature and the polygon file (land plots) as the join feature and CLOSEST as the match method.

The problem is that the water meters and the land plots do not allign correctly as shown in the figure below and it's adding the same cadaster number to two different water meters.

Is there a way I can tell the program to assign a cadaster number only once and if a second point has this same polygon as the closest one to move on to the second closest?

I have some experience with python so if there is a way to do  it this way it won't be a problem.

The drawing attached is just a simple example, what I actually have is this problem for a whole city so I can't just move the water meters manually.

[image]

Comment: If there are no attributes that link the two datasets, and it's not always the closest meter, how would you ever know if it's the correct meter that's been joined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[using QGIS, but I am sure there are equivalent tools in ArcGIS)

In that case you can try the `Distance to nearest hub` tool that you can find under the **Processing Toolbox** of **QGIS**. This tool will give you lines containing the attributes of your counters (i.e the hubs) and the ids of the nearest plots/houses. You can then join this attribute table to the table of your plots layer. I include a screenshot.

Of course this will only work if the data you have is 'regular' as the sample you depict, there are cases for which it might fail (having more counters than parcels or or having a parcel whose counter is actually closer to some other parcel).

[image]

Comment: Sorry for not answering sooner, I was out of town. Based on your reply I did some digging and I think a Near Analysis will do the job or at least it will make it easier. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose in the attribute table of the counters there is no field saying to what parcel is the counter associated? That would make your life much easier - a simple join by attribute.

Comment: Sadly there is no connection between the counters and the parcels as they were two different surveying projects done with several years of difference.